# dedicating the same color to the nodes that have the same label

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j. I have a .csv file with 2 columns (Fname and Lname). I want to write a query that takes each column and creates nodes based on their values. I mean I want to create nodes for Lname column and nodes for Fname column. Here is the query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS row
WITH row.Fname AS first, row.Lname AS last
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first})
...
```

My problem is that all nodes have the same color and all of them are gray. How can I change the query in a way that the nodes of a specific label, have the same color? For example nodes "p" that have the "la" label, have blue colors and nodes "o" that have the "fi" label have the "green" color?

Is it possible to achieve this through the query?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a good practice, user camel case for your node labels. Let's say you have Firstname and Lastname as your labels. When you query your nodes in Neo4j admin console, you see the labels at the top left:

[image]

Now to color labels differently, click on the label and then choose the color you want at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this automatically (through the query maybe)?

Comment: No. But remember when you do this once, it will stay there. Alternatively you can look at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/.